# Setting up a mysql "search" page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need some help on how to set up this page. Let's say I have a mysql table of 5 or so fields of data (i.e. id, firstname, lastname, favorite color, favorite number). I would like to give the user the ability to search the table, so I create a "Search" page.

On the page, I'll have text fields for ID, lastname and firstname.  From here the user would insert data to search by. I guess what I'm confused about is how I can write a script that takes in different search criteria from the text fields and ignore the fields that are left blank. For example, if a user only puts in a first or last name, then all the entries with that same first/last name will be shown. If they only insert the id (would be unique), then all the content for that user will be shown. If they put in both a last name and a last name, then all the data for entries having that first and last name will appear.

I suppose this is basic but I'm new to this so any help on how to set this up would be greatly appreciated.

Code Update:

```
<?php
//Connect and select database

//if user wants to search
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$sqlConditions = array();

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id = filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$sqlConditions[] = 'id = ' . $id;
} else {
$id = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){
$firstName = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sqlConditions[] = 'firstname = ' . $firstName;
} else {
$firstName = '';
}

if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){
$lastName = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sqlConditions[] = 'lastname = ' . $lastName;
} else {
$lastName = '';
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM students WHERE ' . join (' AND ', $sqlConditions);

//print query
while ($row = $query->fetch_row())
{
  print "LastName = " . $row[0] . " FirstName = " . $row[1].
"Favorite Color = " . $row[2] . " Favorite Number = " . $row[3] . "<br /><br />\n";
}

}
?>


<html>
<body>
<form method = "POST" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<p>ID:<input type = "id" id="id" name="id" size="20" maxlength="40" /></p>
<p>First Name:<input type = "firstname" id="firstname" name="firstname" size="20" maxlength="40" /></p>
<p>Last Name:<input type = "lastname" id="lastname" name="lastname" size="20"    maxlength="40" /></p>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name ="submit" value="Search" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following approach:

Step 1: get data from POST, validate it and compose the future sql conditions

```
$sqlConditions = array();

if(isset($_POST['Id'])){
  $id = filter_var($_POST['Id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
  $sqlConditions[] = 'Id = ' . $id;
} else {
  $id = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['FirstName'])){
  $firstName = filter_var($_POST['FirstName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $sqlConditions[] = 'FirstName = ' . $firstName;
} else {
  $firstName = '';
}

if(isset($_POST['LastName'])){
  $lastName = filter_var($_POST['LastName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $sqlConditions[] = 'LastName = ' . $lastName;
} else {
  $lastName = '';
}
```

Step 2: Compose the query

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ' . join (' AND ', $sqlConditions);
```

Of course you will need to use mysql_real_escape_string or some modern approach as PDO to make sure you avoid SQL injection.

Comment: This is great!  I tried this method (see my updated code above), however I can't seem to get the results to print on the page.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Thanks :)

Comment: $query is just a string. You need to execute the query and after that you may fetch the results. Please read: http://php.net/PDO

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I began reading and although confusing, I came up with this:$result = $connection->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($row);...is this what I need?  I tried this, but I was forwarded to a blank page.

Comment: Yes, that's the approach but most probably you have now a fatal error.  Set the display_errors to 1 and user error_reporting(E_ALL) to debug the script.

Answer (score 2):

I am writing this to people who are just starting out PHP.  I apologize to the OP if they are a PHP pro, but this site is for everyone!

So, Here is what I suggest you do:

1. Write a simple script that is able to [connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) and select/display information from your populated table.
2. After you understand how that works, learn how to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). This will protect you from things like [SQL injections](http://xkcd.com/327/) *****
3. Once you understand how these two things work.  All you have to do is make an HTML form (this is easy to find help on with Sir Google) and then use your $_GET or $_POST to access the input from the user and get your information. (if you don't understand the difference between GET and POST, please look that up too!)

If you can learn these things, you'll be well on your way.  Also, knowing how LIKE works will do you good too:

`SELECT stuff FROM myTable WHERE someCondition LIKE '%Me%'`

***(IF YOU LEARN ONE THING FROM THIS ANSWER *PLEASE* REMEMBER THIS)**

Answer (score 1):

In what language is your "search" page?

In general you just need to find out first which of the elements the user completed i.e. are not empty.If you are talking about a web page you can use javascript to determine if a field is empty or not.

Then you should have different queries depending on the fields combination written for example in php to execute the query and get the results.

```
if (lastnameStr!=null)
 {
  <?php
  $result = mysql_query('SELECT lastname FROM tableName );
  if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
  ?>
 }
else
 { 
....
 }
}
```